# How to hide datetimepicker after selecting date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam using datetimepicker from jquery

```
$(".calendarField").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: "d-m-Y",
        })
```

I have declared timepicker is false

Even after selecting the date. The widget is not closing. We have to do double click, then only it will hide.

I want to hide the widget on selecting the date(Single Click)

I tried these possiblities, but it is not working,

```
autoclose:true

onChangeDateTime: function(current_time, $input) {
            $input.data("Date", current_time.getTime());
        }
```

Comment: Check you console for errors. The default behaviour is to close after date is selected like in [this demo](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in your datepicker `autoclose: true`

```
$(".calendarField").datetimepicker({
    format: "d-m-Y",
    autoclose: true
 })
```

**OR**

just add a change event to your input that will fire when value changes. You can then close datepicker there, like this:

```
$('.yourInputClass').on('change', function(){
   $('.datepicker').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `changeDate` Event :
here is an example with `changeDate` event:

```
$('#yourid').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

also you can set `autoClose : true`

```
$('#yourid').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need time section of the dateTimePicker, you can use datePicker instead
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/